# Ubuntu Server Configuration -- Harddrive Partitioning

Tags: server, 14.04

Currently Ubuntu Server is telling me that when I'm making a new partition for Ubuntu Server on this NTFS 1TB HD that I currently have installed to the hardware, that the partition must be a minimum of 52% of the hard drive space or ~521GB. I'm almost positive that this will run into other data, as I have quite a bit of stuff on the hard drive currently.

Can I not make a Ubuntu server partition on that hard drive at like 100GB or something?

Why does it require so much?

Answer (score 0):

First, you really should not use NTFS for your linux (root) partition, use ext4.

Second you can install a server in as few as 5 gb + additional space for data. with modern large hard drives, I suggest 20 gb for root.

I am not sure why the installer is making such a large root partition, I syggest advanced partitioning.